# Why would a header key with a null value in a GET request exist on some requests, but not others?

Tags: javascript, get, http-headers, fetch-api

I'm using JWT for authentication, for any endpoint thats authenticated, I pass a Authorization key in the request, like so:

```
headers: {
  Accept: "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
},
```

I have some endpoints, that don't *require* the user to be authenticated, but if they are, I handle it differently. For example, I may have an endpoint that returns a list of objects. Any user can search and get this list of objects. However, if a user is logged in, I will return the same list of objects with some user data, such as if a user has "liked" one of these objects. Then on the frontend I can just check if a user is logged in, then I expect the response to have a "liked" key.

For these endpoints, the headers look like this:

```
headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: user ? `Bearer ${user.token}` : null,
    },
```

and in the Middleware I check for the token with:

```
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    if (!token) {
      req.userId = null;
      next();
      return;
    }
    ...
```

This has worked fine for the 4-5 weeks my app has been live with ~10000 sessions. However, we started getting a lot of traffic, roughly 5000-6000 sessions a day, and suddenly I'm starting to see an error every few hours in our logs stemming from this middleware with: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')`. Which means that headers must not have the `Authorization` key, because otherwise Authorization would be `null`.

I've already put in a fix to check for `Authorization`, and if it doesnt exist at all to handle that. But I still dont quite understand why sometimes null `Authorization` gets to the server with:

```
headers: {
  Accept: "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Authorization: null,
}
```

And sometimes the request drops the null key and i just get:

```
headers: {
  Accept: "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
```

I dont know what device or what browser these failing requests are coming from. So Im just curious, are there certain browsers/devices that strip out null headers?

Comment: There is no such thing as a null http request header. Either the client sends a string value or it does not send the header. Please check what authorization the client is actually sending, not what you think it is sending.